# how to force svg to be behind div element like in z-index

Tags: svg

my case is that i use `<svg><rect>` for border, this is the code

```
<div class="dotted w-440">
    <svg class="Rectangle_1184 w-440 h-340">
        <rect id="Rectangle_1184" class=" w-440 h-340"></rect>
    </svg>

    <div class="flex-col-center upload h-340">

        buttons and spans....

    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.dotted{position: relative;margin: auto;padding: 8px 0;}
.h-340{height: 335px;}
.w-440{width: 440px;}
.Rectangle_1184{position: absolute;top: 23px;left: 0;}
#Rectangle_1184 {fill: transparent;stroke: rgba(68,73,89,0.502);stroke-dasharray: 6 6;stroke-width: 3px;}
```

when i try to click on a `button` i cant, since the selectable element is onl the `svg`, z-index not working, how can i "move" the `div` content in-front of the svg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, i need to draw another `svg` inside the `div` like this

```
<div class="flex-col-center upload h-340">
        stuff....
    <div class="flex-col-center group-2">
        inner stuff....
        <svg class="svg-btn"><rect class="svg-btn"></rect></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

css
`.svg-btn{position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;}`

EXPLAINATION

with `svg`'s, the browser draws them one upon the other, so once i have another `svg` inside the inner elements it draws them on the big svg